# Keyboard not responding at login on Toshiba Satellite L775

Tags: keyboard, laptop

Just created a separate partition to load Ubuntu 12.04 as a dual boot on a Toshiba Satellite L775. OS installed perfectly and is running flawlessly. The keyboard is not responding at login screen randomly. The virtual keyboard works and the mouse works but the keyboard is unresponsive. After rebooting a couple of times it is responsive again and works with no issues. Went in to keyboard shortcuts and disabled a few of the superfluous media short cut keys in the off chance that it is hinging on a rogue key command that this series of laptop uses. Is there a command line that will debug this issue? Thanks

Comment: I was unable to use the keyboard on my Satellite 775 with any Linux distro I tried. I found that if I unplugged the USB wireles mouse the keyboard worked fine. Must be some kind of device driver conflict or whatever it's equivalent is in Linux. However, when I run Ubuntu inside VM Player, I can use both the mouse and the keyboard. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do this still happens?

Answer (score 0):

In the past this http://www.techsmartlife.com/2011/10/13/keyboard-not-working-in-ubuntu-login-screen/ was helpful.. give it a try. don't know of any command line tools to troubleshoot keyboard.

Comment: Link is no longer in existence!!